# CLRMD Architecture MisMatch

Tags: c#, clrmd

I am working on CLRMD library and trying to load a dump. I am getting Mismatched architecture between this process and the dac. Console applicatin which is x86 application which creates a string array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] strArray = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            strArray = new string[100];
            strArray[i] = "One";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(i); 
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

I used 32Bit TaskManager to create a dump and when I load the dump I get the Architecture mismatch error.

[image]

dataTarget.Architecture is Amd64 and PointerSize 8.

[image]

But When same application process is attached, dataTarget.Architecture is x86 and Pointersize is 4.

[image]

Don't know when this difference. am I missing something when I am taking the dump. Please let me know how to load the dump into CLRMD

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very straight-forward mismatch, your program runs as a 32-bit process but the minidump was created from a 64-bit process.  The DAC does not support mixing.

You have to remove the jitter forcing so your program runs as a 64-bit process as well.  Project > Properties > Build tab, change the Platform target setting to AnyCPU and untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Do note that the solution platform name is not relevant to this setting, a possible reason your test console app turned out to be a 64-bit process even though you thought it targeted x86.  You can double-check with Task Manager, Details tab, add the "Platform" column.

Comment: Thanks you Hans passant. I was using the task manager to take the dump but dump is x64 dump not x86 dump. And I am using procdump application from system internals to take the x86dump.